# Android- save date and text to SQLite in phone's internal memory?

Tags: android, sqlite, button, datepicker, android-edittext

I currently have a layout with an EditText field, Datepicker, and a button. I'm trying to find a code that would make it so when the button is pressed, the values of the datepicker and edittext are stored in a SQL file so that it may be retrieved later.

I'm fairly new to using the SQLite functionality on android, and couldn't find a solution to this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly read documentation regarding SQLite database from

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
2. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqlite

To store value on click of button follow the steps.

1. Create `DbHelper class extends SQLiteOpenHelper` in which you can create table for required values to store in database for e.g. db.execSQL("create table "+EXAMPLE_TABLE+" ("+EDIT+" text, "+DATE+" text )");
2. Create a `class ExampleProvider extends ContentProvider` which manages queries like insert, query(select) , delete and update.
3. After that on click on button retrieve the values from edit text and datepicker , then store it into one object and then using resolver fire the insert query.
4. Check out from commandline whether values inserted into db or not.
5. Similarly you can retrieve values from your databases using `query()` method which retrieve data in form of cursor .